# Django + Pinax to build turn-based web game

Tags: django

I have an aim in mind - which is to create a turn-based web game. Basically the game can accommodate 10 players, each of them input the decisions everyday, and the game will refresh (and do all the calculations) and proceed to the next turn everyday.

I'm starting to look into Django to build the codes and probably use some reusable features from Pinax (user registration, twitter shoutout etc...)

Do you think that I'm on a right direction, and some advises will be greatly appreciated!

Thank you very much!

Comment: Django can accommodate what you're describing.  Look into [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#configuring-your-django-project-to-use-celery) for scheduling nightly computations. However, this question is pretty general for SO and you might not get much attention.  Get started, do what you can, and come here with your specific problems.  Good luck!

Comment: Hi dokkaebi, thanks for the advice. I will start working on it, and probably post some codes in SO if I have any questions. Thanks again!